# No integration defined for method - select stage where your API will be deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

[image]

I'm working with AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda. I face this type of error message when attempt to deploy API. The error message says to select a deployment stage. But I still selecting and trying to deploy! but giving the  error! anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your are missing some configuration in your api method resource. Is it all set with Method Request, Integration Request and Method Response? Your Integration Request is set to Lambda_Proxy? All set with Method Response? Did you add a 200 response on it?

[image: Integration Request for Lambda]